# Haddock - Trying to use named block while documenting class method

Tags: haskell, haddock

Is it possible to document a class method with Haddock and query pieces of documentation in the instance declaration code?

For exemple, I would like the class documented like this :

```
class ModifMATH a  where
  -- | Explanations of simpMath method.
  -- 
  --
  -- $part1
  -- $part2
  -- $part3      
  simpMath :: a -> a
```

and the instance documented like this :

```
instance ModifMATH MathExpress where
  -- $part1 a piece of explanation
  simpMath (MathDouble n)            = ...   

  -- $part2 another explanation 
  simpMath (MathMult a b)   = ...

  -- $part3 end of explanations 
  simpMath (MathAdd a b)   =  ...
```

and get the html Haddock documentation look like this (sorry i have no image) :

```
class ModifMATH a where
   Methods
      simpMath :: a -> a
         Explanations of simpMath method.
         a piece of explanation
         another explanation
         end of explanations
```

This organization of documentation would be more readable and extensible when adding patterns in the instance while keeping the whole method documentation in a stand-alone paragraph. Is it possible?

I'm using Haddock version 2.10.0. on Debian 7.0.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to split up documentation like this.

The only place where it was possible to more or less do this was in [case of some questionable use of record fields](https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/195) but does not apply here and we have changed this behaviour in 2.14.x.

Perhaps you could use [a definition list](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html#idp1371096868) to try and get some natural split in your documentation. For example, something like

```
class ModifMATH a  where
  -- | Explanations of simpMath method.
  -- 
  -- [MathDouble case] $part1
  --
  -- [MathMult case] $part2
  --
  -- [MathAdd case] $part3      
  simpMath :: a -> a
```

Please note that the docs refer to the 2.14.x version which is quite a a bit newer than what you're using so for example those newlines between each definition list are necessary.

It should look more or less like:

[image: deflist]
<sub>(source: [fuuzetsu.co.uk](http://fuuzetsu.co.uk/images/1399715808.png))</sub>

You can go multi-line if needed, refer to the docs.